# Search result preview returns title and url, is there a way to only show custom site columns in the result?

Tags: search, search-results, query, content-search-web-part, search-query

I've got a list with one item (site columns: title, license). Is there a way to retrieve only what's inside license based on the query text? (content search web part)

I've tried to use {|License(from managed property)} without any luck.

Then you probably say "yes with a display template", and that's correct. But ..

What I'm actually trying to do is to match two lists. Something like this...

```
path:"http://conpamy.com/Lists/Licenses/"  
(IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") 
title:{path:"http://company.com/workspaces/TeamSiteTest/Lists/SiteProperties/"{|License} }
```